# How can I add pagination to my existing code?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo, pagination

I would like to add pagination to my existing table which I have programmed using ajax.

I have tried multiple pagination solutions and none of them looks like its compatible with my existing table which I have right now

Table in index.php

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
    <th width="5%"></th>
    <th width="10%">Serial No.</th>
    <th width="20%">Equipment Type</th>
    <th width="15%">Document Remarks</th>
    <th width="10%">Supplier</th>
    <th width="10%">Date In</th>
    <th width="10%">Customer</th>
    <th width="10%">Date Out</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Script for showing table in index.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function fetch_data()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "select.php",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var html = '';
                    for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
                    {
                        html += '<tr>';
                        html += '<td><input type="checkbox" value="' + 
data[count].id + '" id="' + data[count].id + '" data-serial_number="' + 
data[count].serial_number + '" data-equipment_type="' + 
data[count].equipment_type + '" data-document_remarks="' + 
data[count].document_remarks + '" data-supplier="' + data[count].supplier + 
'" data-date_scan="' + data[count].date_scan + '" data-customer="' + 
data[count].customer + '" data-date_out="' + data[count].date_out + '" 
class="check_box"  /></td>';
                        html += '<td>' + data[count].serial_number + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + data[count].equipment_type + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + data[count].document_remarks + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + data[count].supplier + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + data[count].date_scan + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + data[count].customer + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + data[count].date_out + '</td></tr>';
                    }
                $('tbody').html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    fetch_data();
 }
</script>
```

select.php

```
include('database_connection.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY id DESC";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

if ($statement->execute()) {
    while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "none of them looks like its compatible with my existing table"?

Comment: @GregSchmidt To me, as I'm a student I'm not quite sure how to apply the pagination solution to my existing table.

Answer (score 1):

In your `fetch_data()` function you will need to include page data in your POST request:

- `limit` should be the number of items viewable per page
- `offset` should be `limit` multiplied by the page number (starting at 0)

Ex. below would request the second page of results (10 results per page)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "select.php",
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {limit: 10, offset: 10},
  // etc.
```

The in your PHP script you will need to read these variables and add them to your query:

```
$limit = $_POST['limit'];
$offset= $_POST['offset'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT = ? OFFSET= ?";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

if ($statement->execute([$limit, $offset])) {
    while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! I tried this and my sql data isn't showing in my table :(, do I leave the question marks in the select query as is?

Comment: @QairulShazriz Yes the question marks are part of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Do you have more than 10 rows in the inventory table you are trying to show?

Comment: Yes the database currently has over 300+ data and it will keep increasing. So how do I go about it? I appreciate it so much for helping me

Comment: Does running this query against your DB returns results:`SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT = 10 OFFSET= 10`

Comment: Sadly not a single result came through.